# Embarcadero RAD Server, cannot get Apache server to run RAD Server DLL

Tags: api, apache, delphi, rad-server

I've set up Embarcadero RAD Server on a web server, I've got the standalone executable running, which works perfectly. I'd like to get Apache to execute the DLL, so instead of having an application sitting there, it runs quietly in the background. RAD Server had a DLL which, from my understanding is supposed to plug into Apache and be executed by apache.

I've followed the tutorials on embarcadero's website for achieving this, what happens at the moment is apache just refuses to run when I've got it configured to use the RAD Server DLL, when I remove the lines from the httpd.conf file Apache starts again as normal.

Has anyone experienced a similar problem? it's not an issue with the configuration of RAD Server, as the standalone executable would not work if there was; that is unless there's something that needs to change for the Apache to use the DLL to run RAD Server.

Please let me know if there's anymore information that would be useful for me to supply.

I've followed the instructions from the Embarcadero website, so I've tried including all of the RAD Server DLL's in the same folder as the RAD Server DLL. I've tried modifying the config settings, removed my custom API BPL to allow just rad server to run, and it also fails. I would have expected that following the embardaero instructions with a basic RAD Server DLL file it should work.

There must be something I'm missing when I do the configuration.

Comment: I run Rad Server under IIS, which even though they have tutorials, it was a trial and error process.  I recommend creating a support ticket with Embarcadero.. not too many Rad Server users on SO.

Comment: Does Apache hang upon loading the DLL or does it continue to load subsequent modules after the DLL or does it quit? Open Sysinternal's Process Explorer and inspect Apache to see which DLLs it loaded.

Comment: It often helped me to start apache in a console and see what output it generated. Sometimes there are some good hints there. In addition I always try to debug the apache server by issuing "httpd.exe" with a parameter -X which starts only one instance of server. This makes dbugging A LOT easier. Can you create a breakpoint at the programs begin? If not the module seems not to be loaded...